# Thread pool (presumably) locking issue with condition variable and mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I'm working on a thread pool and ran into a weird issue regarding condition variables and mutexes. I suspect there might be a locking problem since it sometimes works, sometimes it doesn't. This is the relevant part of the code (removed non-relevant bits):

```
class ThreadPool {
  private:
    std::atomic<bool> running;
    std::atomic<size_t> unfinished_tasks;
    std::queue<std::function<void(void)>> task_queue;
    std::condition_variable cv_work;
    std::mutex mtx_queue;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

  public:
    ThreadPool(size_t num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency());
    ~ThreadPool();

    template<class T, class Fn>
    std::future<T> queueTask(Fn&& fn);
};

ThreadPool::ThreadPool(size_t num_threads) :
    running(true), unfinished_tasks(0) {
  auto thread_loop = [&] {
    while (running.load()) {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx_queue);
      if (!task_queue.empty()) {
        auto work = task_queue.front();
        task_queue.pop();
        lock.unlock();
        work();
        unfinished_tasks--;
      } else {
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " going to sleep..." << std::endl;
        cv_work.wait(lock);
      }
    }};
  threads.reserve(num_threads);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
    threads.push_back(std::thread(thread_loop));
  }
}

template<class T, class Fn>
inline std::future<T> ThreadPool::queueTask(Fn&& fn) {
  // func = lambda containing packaged task with fn
  mtx_queue.lock();
  task_queue.push(func);
  mtx_queue.unlock();
  unfinished_tasks++;
  cv_work.notify_one();
  return future;
}
```

As soon as I comment out the line containing the debug output, adding lots of small tasks to the thread pool will make it lock up at some point, with the debug output in place, it will finish all tasks properly. I'm not really sure where the issue could be here.

Comment: It's likely that the implementation of  <threads> already uses a thread-pool. In any case, do some research on how to use condition_variable in conjunction with `std::unique_lock`.  You're doing it all wrong.

Comment: I don't think it does. std::async would be more likely to be implemented as thread pool but that doesn't seem to be the case either.

Comment: Watch this: https://youtu.be/qH6sSOr-yk8?t=33m37s

Comment: I would recommend benchmarking against `std::thread` and `std::async`.  On Windows/Visual C++17, they use the native winapi threadpool, which has got to be better than any roll-your-own could be.

Comment: I did benchmark against std::async and std::thread on Linux Mint which is slower at creating a lot of small tasks, assumingly from the overhead of creating a thread for each task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition.  `queueTask` can notify `cv_work` before your thread function is waiting.  Don't unlock `mtx_queue` until after you call `cv_work.notify_one()`.

Comment: The (a?) disease is diagnosed, but I think that's the wrong medicine. A condition_variable `wait` with no test for a condition is a BRF (big red flag).

Comment: Ah, yeah that seems to be it. I'll do some mroe tests to be sure.

Comment: @JiveDadson - Not sure it makes a diffrence in this case. If it's a spurious wakeup it'll fail the if and go right back to waiting.  Am I missing something?  That being said, good catch.

Comment: I have not looked very carefully at the code, but I've seen similar (mis)uses of cv.wait that are a subject not just to spurious wakeups, but also missed wakeups.  Testing will very seldom catch such problems. You find out about them when a customer calls and says the program will run for a few hours or days and then hang.